panic: all modules must be defined when setting SetOrderInitGenesis, missing: [checkers]
ubunutu : 22.04 LTS
golang : 1.21.0
cosmos sdk : v0.5.0
minid : mini-v050
followed tutorial : https://tutorials.cosmos.network/hands-on-exercise/0-native/2-build-module.html
After building my own checkers module. I am integrating it with chain-minimal but while I run minid start getting below error
panic: all modules must be defined when setting SetOrderInitGenesis, missing: [checkers]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/types/module.(*Manager).assertNoForgottenModules(0xc0015a1ee0, {0x22822b8, 0x13}, {0xc000cba480, 0x5, 0xc000cf56c0?}, 0xc001398500)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/types/module/module.go:634 +0x365
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/types/module.(*Manager).SetOrderInitGenesis(0xc0015a1ee0, {0xc000cba480, 0x5, 0x8})
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/types/module/module.go:347 +0x5c
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/runtime.(*App).Load(0xc0007cd500, 0x1)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/runtime/app.go:106 +0x4b
github.com/cosmosregistry/chain-minimal/app.NewMiniApp({0x2c69428?, 0xc000a85110}, {0x2c79260, 0xc00031a010}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x12?, {0x2c3d8e0?, 0xc000af5a40}, {0xc000a84150, ...})
    /home/rahul/Desktop/Learning/cosmos/chain-minimal/app/app.go:153 +0x7a5
github.com/cosmosregistry/chain-minimal/cmd/minid/cmd.newApp({0x2c69428, 0xc000a85110}, {0x2c79260, 0xc00031a010}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x2c3d8e0, 0xc000af5a40})
    /home/rahul/Desktop/Learning/cosmos/chain-minimal/cmd/minid/cmd/commands.go:104 +0xaa
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server.startApp(0xc0004e2940, 0x2a0ac08, {0x2a0b368, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2a0b378})
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/start.go:618 +0x215
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server.start(_, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x2c7e8c8, 0xc000905860}, 0x0, {0xc0008754a8, 0x4}, {0x2c92420, ...}, ...}, ...)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/start.go:224 +0x159
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server.StartCmdWithOptions.func2.1()
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/start.go:198 +0x6d
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server.wrapCPUProfile(0xc0004e2940, 0xc000c9f808)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/start.go:570 +0x1b3
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server.StartCmdWithOptions.func2(0xc00087dd00?, {0x4060c60?, 0x0?, 0x0?})
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/start.go:197 +0x212
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0002e3500, {0x4060c60, 0x0, 0x0})
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:985 +0xabc
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc000be9500)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:1117 +0x3ff
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:1041
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteContext(...)
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.1/command.go:1034
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/server/cmd.Execute(0x40b34b?, {0x0, 0x0}, {0xc000cb65b8, 0x12})
    /home/rahul/go/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.50.10/server/cmd/execute.go:34 +0x187
main.main()
    /home/rahul/Desktop/Learning/cosmos/chain-minimal/cmd/minid/main.go:18 +0x38```


The problem lies with the list of modules used for chain initialization. The tutorial repository provides a list that does not include your new checkers module.
To solve this problem you need to edit app.yml file of chain-minimal repository to include the checkers module in the initialization list (besides just adding a reference to its Module protobuf).
The relevant section that needs to be updated from:
init_genesis: [auth, bank, distribution, staking, genutil]

To:
init_genesis: [auth, bank, distribution, staking, genutil, checkers]

